# How to index numpy array with given indexes?

Tags: python, numpy

## Question: How to index numpy array with given indexes?

### Discription

In reinforcement learning, I got many discrete distributions corresponding to different states, like the following:

```py
import numpy as np
distributions = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.7],[0.3,0.3,0.4],[0.2,0.2,0.6]])

# array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.7],  # \pi(s0)
#        [0.3, 0.3, 0.4],  # \pi(s1)
#        [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]]) # \pi(s2)
```

Then, I want to get the probabilities of taking action 0 in state `s0`, taking action 2 in state `s1`, and taking action 1 in state `s2` respectively.

So I stored the index value in a array like the following:

```py
actions = np.array([[0],[2],[1]])

# array([[0],  # taking action 0 in state s0
#        [2],  # taking action 2 in state s1
#        [1]]) # taking action 1 in state s2
```

### What I expected to get.

I want to index `distributions` using `actions`, and expect to get the the result like:

```py
# array([0.1,0.4,0.2])
# or 
# array([[0.1],
#        [0.4],
#        [0.2]])
```

### What I tried.

I've tried `np.take(distributions, actions)`, but the retun `array([0.1, 0.7, 0.2])` was obviously what I wanted. 
And I also tried `distributions[:,actions]`, which gave me another wrong answer as bellow:

```py
array([[0.1, 0.7, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.4, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.6, 0.2]])
```

### Question

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What? "uerdefined"? What word did you mean to use there?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the wrong spelling. I mean "user-defined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [614]: distributions = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.7],[0.3,0.3,0.4],[0.2,0.2,0.6]]) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [615]: actions = np.array([[0],[2],[1]])
```

Use a [0,1,2] row index:

```
In [616]: distributions[np.arange(3), actions]                                  
Out[616]: 
array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.2],
       [0.7, 0.4, 0.6],
       [0.2, 0.3, 0.2]])
```

oops, `actions` is (3,1) shape, which broadcasts with (3,) to produce a (3,3) selection.  Instead we want to use a (3,) shaped `actions`:

```
In [617]: distributions[np.arange(3), actions.ravel()]                          
Out[617]: array([0.1, 0.4, 0.2])
```

or to get a (3,1) result:

```
In [619]: distributions[[[0],[1],[2]], actions]                                 
Out[619]: 
array([[0.1],
       [0.4],
       [0.2]])
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer!  So, the code is: ```distributions[[[0],[1],[2]],[[0],[2],[1]]]``` or ```distributions[[0,1,2],[0,2,1]]```.